# How to find critical numbers in awkward function

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative

I have problem to find critical numbers in this awkward function with Euler's constants.

$$f(x, y) =  e^{2 x+3 y} \left(8 x^2-6 x y+3 y^2\right)$$

[Task: Find critical numbers and determine if it's maximum or minimum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib6k6.png)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to MSE! If you include an English translate (or tag your post as [tag:translation-request]), it's more likely to get an answer. Also, can you share what you've tried and what you're having trouble with? Did you compute the partial derivatives of your function yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We find $f_x$ and $f_y$ set them equal to zero and find the critical points.

$$f_x = 2 e^{2 x+3 y} \left(8 x^2-6 x y+3 y^2\right)+e^{2 x+3 y} (16 x-6 y)=0$$

$$f_y = 3 e^{2 x+3 y} \left(8 x^2-6 x y+3 y^2\right)+e^{2 x+3 y} (6 y-6 x)=0$$

Clearly the exponential terms do not give zeros (divide those out), so we are left with solving:

$$2 \left(8 x^2-6 x y+3 y^2\right)+ (16 x-6 y)=0$$

$$3 \left(8 x^2-6 x y+3 y^2\right)+ (6 y-6 x)=0$$

Solving these leads to two critical points:

$$(x, y) = (0, 0), \left(-\dfrac{1}{4}, -\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$$

You can now try to classify them.